# I can't get the button to change if statements

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public class calcButtonHandler3 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a)
    {
        DecimalFormat num3 = new DecimalFormat(",###.##");
        double feet, milli, meters, yards, inches;

        String str1 = tFeet.getText();
        String str2 = tYards.getText();
        String str3 = tInches.getText();
        String str4 = tMeters.getText();
        String str5 = tMilli.getText();

        if (str1 != "")
        {
            feet = Double.parseDouble(tFeet.getText());

            yards = feet / 3;
            inches = feet * 12;
            milli = feet * 304.8;
            meters = feet * 0.3048;

            tYards.setText(num3.format(yards));
            tInches.setText(num3.format(inches));
            tMilli.setText(num3.format(milli));
            tMeters.setText(num3.format(meters));
        }

        else if (str2 != "")
        {
            yards = Double.parseDouble(tYards.getText());

            feet = yards * 3;
            inches = yards * 36;
            milli = yards * 914.4;
            meters = yards * 0.9144;

            tFeet.setText(num3.format(feet));
            tInches.setText(num3.format(inches));
            tMilli.setText(num3.format(milli));
            tMeters.setText(num3.format(meters));
        }

        else if (str3 != "")
        {
            inches = Double.parseDouble(tInches.getText());

            feet = inches * 3;
            yards = inches * 36;
            milli = inches * 25.4;
            meters = inches * 0.0254;

            tFeet.setText(num3.format(feet));
            tYards.setText(num3.format(yards));
            tMilli.setText(num3.format(milli));
            tMeters.setText(num3.format(meters));
        }

        else if (str4 != "")
        {
            meters = Double.parseDouble(tMeters.getText());

            feet = meters * 3.2808399;
            inches = meters * 39.37007874;
            milli = meters * 1000 ;
            yards = meters * 1.0936133;

            tFeet.setText(num3.format(feet));
            tInches.setText(num3.format(inches));
            tMilli.setText(num3.format(milli));
            tYards.setText(num3.format(yards));
        }

        else if (str5 != "")
        {
            milli = Double.parseDouble(tMilli.getText());

            feet = milli * 0.00328084;
            inches = milli * 0.03937008;
            yards = milli * 0.00109361;
            meters = milli / 1000;

            tFeet.setText(num3.format(feet));
            tInches.setText(num3.format(inches));
            tYards.setText(num3.format(yards));
            tMeters.setText(num3.format(meters));
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a number");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the button to switch to the other if statements? when I run this code if nothing is in the tFeet Field, then nothing happens.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "nothing happens"? Also, did you try placing breakpoints and seeing which code is executed in the case you described?

Comment: By "nothing happens" I mean that the console just shows some errors. the only code that executes is the very first if statement and that is only when I input data into that text field.

Comment: Please add the errors that you see, that could help.

Comment: I figured it out. That break comment was exactly the hint I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Breakpoints are your friends :)

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are not mutually exclusive.

```
if (str1 != "")...  
else if (str2 != "")...  
else if (str3 != "")...  
else if (str4 != "")...  
else if (str5 != "")...
```

Those should be five separate `if` statements instead of one `if...else if` statement if you need all of them to execute.

Also, you should be using the String `equals` method to compare String values.

```
if (!str1.equals(""))...
```